# async function with cloud functions (syntax error on async)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have the following code in my index.js:

```
exports.queryAPI = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors(request, response, () => {
    return APICall(request.params.searchTerm).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      }).catch(() => {
        return response.status(400).json({ error: 'Something went wrong.' });
      })
  });
});

async function APICall(search) {
  const response = await apicalypse({
    queryMethod: "body",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'user-key': API_KEY
    },
    responseType: 'json',
    timeout: 1000,
    })
    .fields(["name"]) // fetches only the name and movies fields
    .search(search) // search for a specific name (search implementations can vary)

    // .where("age > 50 & movies != n") // filter the results
    // .where(["age > 50", "movies != n"]) // same as above
    .request(API_URL);

  return response.data;
}
```

When I try to deploy this function I get the following error:

```
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/index.js:34
async function APICall(search) {
      ^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

According to my searches I did the function correct with async. Someone that point where I made my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using a node version less than 8 on your local machine.  Version 8 is the first version that supports ES7 async/await syntax.  So, the first thing is to update your local node installation.  Check the version with `node --version`.

Cloud Functions uses node 6 as a runtime by default, so if you want your deployed code that uses async/await to run, you will also have to tell the Firebase CLI to target node 8.  Node 8 support is in beta. You can read about targeting node 8 in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) and in [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/cloud-functions-for-firebase-config-node-8-timeout-memory-region.html).

Comment: That was indeed my mistake. I had add target Node 8 on the Firebase CLI. Added `"engines": {"node": "8"}` and it deployed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js version 8 is required. Do this on your development machine:

```
nvm install 8.6.1
nvm alias default 8.6.1
```

Then in your `functions` directory, open `package.json` and add:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the reason, but the `await` command only works in index.js for me. If I move the same command to another file and `exports` the function, I get the same compilation error as your `async` error.